# How do I write this JavaScript code in React js. This piece of code works perfectly fine in JavaScript but does'nt work in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This piece of code works perfectly fine in JavaScript but does'nt work in React js. I tried using arrow function but still unable to get the proper output. please let me know what is the mistake.

```
 function addLisHandlers() {
          var lis = document.getElementById("name");
          var rows = lis.getElementsByTagName("li");
          console.log(rows);
          for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var currentRow = rows[i];
            var createClickHandler = function (row) {
              return function () {
                author = row.innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("input").value = author;
                return search_button();
              };
            };enter code here
            currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
          }
        }
```